# Pantheism, panentheism, other combinations?

Tags: theology

To put it simply,

1. Pantheism means God is the whole universe.
2. Panentheism means universe is part of God.

Maybe in mathematical terms we can say that:

1. Pantheism => (God = universe)
2. Panentheism => (universe < God) (or universe is a subset of God, or universe is a member of God seen as a set)

Has anyone ever mentioned the third possibility, that is, God being part of universe, or mathematically representing, (God < universe)? Something like theoenpanism (theos + en + pan)

PS: sorry for poor mathematical notation. I didn't find TeX in action here.

Comment: Many of the "Pagan" religons religate the gods powers to realms, Neptune to the sea, Hades to the underworld...

Comment: It's important to remember that the pagan gods are vastly different from the God of monotheistic religions. Pagan gods are "beings among many", usually forces of nature or humanoids with greater powers, while the monotheistic God is either an impersonal principle or the ground of Being, or a personal ground of being, however ground is understood.

Answer (score 2):

Any god which is not omnipotent/omniscience would immediately fall into that category. Numerous religions throughout the world have Gods or deities which are flawed, exist in the universe as a subset of it, and/or are subject to the universal laws which drive it. However, technically even an Abrahamic God (omnipotent/omniscient) could fall into that category depending on your conception of it. I don't see any inherent conflicts with such a notion.

Comment: The Abrahamic God could not fall into that category; the God-world relationship is creationist (not to be confused with those of the evolution debate), or at best panentheistic as such as deity is both transcendent and imminent in relation to the universe.

Comment: @Robert Not everyone who professes to believe in the Abrahamic God asserts that, e.g. some suggest he must obey the laws of logic (i.e., law of contradiction).

Comment: I'd argue there is an error in the way "laws of logic" are understood. These "laws" are descriptive in relation to metphysics. Logic cannot explain the law of contradiction, it only accepts it as something coming from observation. Thus, it would mean Being is non-contradictory and furthermore I would say this is the result of God being non-contradictory. So it isn't that God obeys any laws but *is* those laws, that is, the laws are part of what God is.

Comment: Also, it isn't the case that any God that is not omnipotent/omniscient would immediately fall into this category. How would that follow? What you seem to mean is that this God would be relatively less powerful than his creation. However, it strikes me as odd to say that a God can create a universe which can be relatively more potent than he is. Or that the universe preexists his creating of it as you seem to imply with the example in the comments.